# preg_replace replacing incorrectly

Tags: php, regex, templates, preg-replace

I've had some help from a friend (who is now away on holiday) but I have a problem with a `preg_replace` search and replace. I don't know why, but it is replacing strings incorrectly which has had a knock on affect to the next one it should replace.

This basically goes within a template class dealing with 'if' and 'else' queries within the template.

```
function if_statement($a, $b, $if, $type, $else = NULL){
    if($type == "1" && is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b)){
        $statement = ($a === $b) ? $if : $else;
    } else if($type == "1"){
        $statement = ($a == $b) ? $if : $else;
    } else if($type == "2"){
        $statement = ($a != $b) ? $if : $else;
    }
    return stripslashes($statement);
}

$output = file_get_contents("template.tpl");

$replace = array(
  '#\<if:"\'(.*?)\' == \'(.*?)\'"\>(.*?)\<else\>(.*?)\<\/endif\>#sei',
  '#\<if:"\'(.*?)\' == \'(.*?)\'"\>(.*?)\<\/endif\>#sei'
);  
$functions = array(
  "if_statement('\\1', '\\2', '\\3', '1', '\\4')",
  "if_statement('\\1', '\\2', '\\3', '1')"
);
$output = preg_replace($replace, $functions, $output);
echo $output;
```

The template:

```
<HTML>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Site Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="common.css" />
    <if:"'{ISADMIN}' == '1'">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin-bar.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    </endif>
</head>
<body>
    <if:"'{TODAY}' == 'Monday'">Today is Monday<else>Today is not Monday</endif>
    <if:"'1' == '2'">1 equals 2!<else>1 doesn't equal 2</endif>
</body>
</html>
```

Where the current output will be below:

```
<HTML>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Site Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="common.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin-bar.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    **</endif>**
</head>
<body>
    **<if:"'{TODAY}' == 'Monday'">**Today is Monday
    1 doesn't equal 2
</body>
</html>
```

In the above, the bolded/astrix makred parts shouldn't be there on the output, and also today isn't Monday. While the admin is logged in, the `admin-bar.css` file has been rightly included, but for some reason isn't picking up the `</endif>` tag - infact, it looks like it has gone after the `<else>` tag instead in the next statement ... in other words, `preg_replace` has matched an incorrect thing! And thus didn't pick up on the 2nd `<if>` statement.

The `{BRACKET}` tags are being replaced correctly - I've even manually put data into the statement (just to check), so they aren't the problem...

I don't know why, but to me `preg_replace` isn't finding the correct sequence to replace and act upon. If anyone could lay a fresh pair of eyes/lend a hand, I would be grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `<if>` in your sample doesn't have an `<else>` clause. Therefore, when `<if:"'(.*?)' == '(.*?)'">(.*?)<else>(.*?)</endif>` (where `<else>` is not optional) is applied to it, it matches all this:

```
    <if:"'{ISADMIN}' == '1'">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin-bar.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    </endif>
</head>
<body>
    <if:"'{TODAY}' == 'Monday'">Today is Monday<else>Today is not Monday</endif>
```

In that match, group `$3` is

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin-bar.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    </endif>
</head>
<body>
    <if:"'{TODAY}' == 'Monday'">Today is Monday
```

You could avoid that by forbidding the regex to cross over an `</endif>` using lookahead assertions:

```
'%<if:\s*"\'([^\']*)\' == \'([^\']*)\'">((?:(?!<else>|</endif>).)*)<else>((?:(?!</endif).)*)</endif>%si'
```

or, in commented form (and possibly more helpful when a programmer again goes "away on holiday"):

```
'%<if:\s*"\'     # Match <if:(optional space)"\'
    ([^\']*)     # Match 0 or more non-quote characters, capture group 1
    \'\s==\s\'   # Match \' == \'
    ([^\']*)     # Match 0 or more non-quote characters, capture group 2
    \'">         # Match \'">
    (            # Capture into group 3:
     (?:         # The following group...
      (?!        # only if we\'re not right before...
       <else>    # <else>
      |          # or
       </endif>  # </endif>
      )          # (End of lookahead assertion)
      .          # Match any character
     )*          # Repeat as necessary
    )            # End of capturing group 3
    <else>       # Match <else>
    (            # Same construction as above, group 4
     (?:
      (?!
       </endif>  # this time only looking for </endif>
      )
      .
     )*
    )
    </endif>     # and finally match </endif>
    %esix'
```

The second regex should also be improved:

```
'%<if:\s*"\'     # Match <if:(optional space)"\'
    ([^\']*)     # Match 0 or more non-quote characters, capture group 1
    \'\s==\s\'   # Match \' == \'
    ([^\']*)     # Match 0 or more non-quote characters, capture group 2
    \'">         # Match \'">
    (            # Capture into group 3:
     (?:
      (?!
       </endif>  # Any text until </endif>
      )
      .
     )*
    )
    </endif>     # and finally match </endif>
    %esix'
```

Also, these regexes should be faster as they specify more clearly what can and cannot be matched, thus avoiding a lot of backtracking.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation Tim! Is it possible to add in a 'space detection after the initial `<if:` eg. so could use either `<if: "'...` as well as `<if:"'...`?